# Arithmetic in array assignments?

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to php and need to do basic PEMDAS arithmetic within an associative array assignment, however am getting syntax errors and cannot seem to find them.

Here is some code.

```
$worth=array(
        'one'=>((1000/333)*$min[0]->getPrice(),
        'two'=>((833/333)*$min[0]->getPrice()) + ((416/333)*$min[1]->getPrice()));
```

These are only two entries of 16.  Each of which have another ((number/number)*$arr[$i]->getPrice()) added to the end of the assignment.

Is this type of array assignment not allowed?

Suggestions on alternatives which may be cleaner?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the errors that you got

Comment: You missed a closing parenthesis at the end of the line that starts 'one'=>.....

Answer (score 1):

thats allowed, you have parenthesis missing, try

```
$worth=array(
        'one'=>(int) ((1000/333)*$min[0]->getPrice()),
        'two'=>(int) (((833/333)*$min[0]->getPrice()) + ((416/333)*$min[1]->getPrice())));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: >.< Thanks, sometimes I suppose its best to get up and walk away when stuck on seemingly correct code.  Eyes completely missed it.